# cookie.js auto adds subdirectory to path

Tags: javascript, cookies, path, directory

I am using Cookie.js to manage read write actions on the page Cookies. I am running more then one app on the development directory so I must set the app root path - this way we can debug multiple apps without session cookies interfering with each other. Why they interfere? Because they all use the same naming scheme.

So, anytime there is a write action I use:

```
Cookies.set(session_var, data, {path: appProprieties.folder});
```

Being all variables, the appProprieties is the current app directory: "app1Folder". This works fine for the homepage. After that, Cookie.js (or whatever its using to set the path) is auto completing the path with a page subdirectory.

Cookies are ending up in : /app1Folder/page2
I tried to slash the folder directory with no success:

```
Cookies.set(session_var, data, {path: appProprieties.folder + "/"});
```

Question: how do I lock the path to this directory? If no path is set it saves to the root "/" in all pages with their respective sub directories. If a path is set it magically starts adding sub directories too it.

Best Regards

Comment: [solved] "/" + appProprieties.folder + "/" solves the problem. A valid path must start with "/". Apparently, if an invalid path is provided the cookie is saved to the current page path and not the root. Hence the behaviour I described.